# Can I backup Hyper-V replica Virtual Machines instead of main VMs?

Tags: virtual-machine, backup, replication, hyper-v

I backup my Hyper-V machines on my main server periodically. I have also turned on replication on different machine where I have also more storage space so my backup VM images go to this secondary machine.

Question is - when I backup replica will I have problems with restoration of VM if I would like to restore replica VM on main hyper-v server?

Can I just backup my  replica VMs and avoid unnecessary file transfer between servers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > Can I just backup my replica VMs and avoid unnecessary file transfer between servers?

You can backup replica VMs , but the result might be not as you expected .

Because :

"

-**Only crash-consistent backup of a Replica VM is guaranteed**.

-**A robust retry mechanism needs to be configured in the backup product to deal with failures. Or ensure that replication is paused when backup is scheduled.**

"

This [artilce](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/virtualization/2014/04/24/backup-of-a-replica-vm/) may guide you in the right direction .